# Trying to print a unicode code point table

Tags: javascript, unicode

I am trying to make a unicode code points table that prints the code points till `U+300`

I change the number into hexadecimal and concatenate it with the unicode escape sequence.

When I try to concatenate the hexadecimal number with `'\u'` I get an error `SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode Escape Sequence`

Here's [the code](https://jsfiddle.net/yousef_essam/xsmLgd7q/29/)

How can I fix that error?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code (and html) in the question itself, rather than posting a link to the problem code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the print statement to `print(num + ' => ' + String.fromCharCode("0x" + num));`

Comment: That won't print the code point in hex (with exactly four hex digits), which is what I think OP is after.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
print(num + ' => ' + '\u' + num);
```

use this:

```
print(num + ' => ' + '\\u' + num);
```

Or, more concisely,

```
print(num + ' => \\u' + num);
```

You need to escape the `\` itself to include it in a string literal.

Comment: it just prints the escape character, i want to print the unicode representation

Comment: i don't want to print `\u` i want to print the unicode representation

Comment: @NoOne -- Well, then replace `'\\u'` with `U+` (or whatever you want to use as a Unicode code point signifier). The reason for the syntax error was trying to use the string literal `'\u'`. That error is all I was addressing in my answer. If it's just printing `\u`, then check why `num` is the empty string.